# Link submodules to one of them in same project

Tags: git, git-submodules

Assuming we have

- Project "core".
- Project "module1" uses "core" as submodule.
- Project "module2" uses "core" as submodule.

Now, I expect to have my "App" source code folder tree like this

- module1 ( as submodule )
- module2 ( as submodule )
- core    ( as submodule )

I want to use both "module1" and "module2" in my app. I see that both of them should use same revision of "core". So my question is may I change the connection of "core" in "module1" and "module2" to the core in same level folder.

Because of this way, for each project, I still can develop them alone.
With "App", I can build them easily, force "module1" and "module" must use same revision of "core".

Thanks for reading.